# Transition functions of trivial vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I have a question on trivial vector bundles. The question is as follows:

> Can we characterize the transition functions of a trivial vector
>   bundle in some way?

To be very concrete: suppose we have a vector bundle $E$, say of rank $3$, on an algebraic variety $X$ (or manifold if you prefer), and  we look at trivial sub-bundles $0\to F\to E$ of rank $2$. What can we say about the transition functions of $F$ if we know those of $E$?

In this particular circumstance, we do have $3\times 3$ matrices at hand, and we want to produce $2\times 2$ matrices. The question is which ones are good.

At the beginning, I thought I could extend an argument of pure linear algebra: if we have an exact sequence of vector spaces $0\to V\to W\to W/V\to 0$, we can complete a basis $(e_1,e_2)$ of $V$ to a basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ of $W$, so that $W\to W/V$ is represented by the row vector $e_3$ and $V\to W$ by the $3\times 2$ matrix containing $e_1,e_2$ written as columns. This didn't bring me anywhere, even because I can't figure how to use the triviality hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bundle is trivial if and only if the cocycle of its transition functions becomes cohomologous to the trivial cocycle $1$ after suitable refinement of the covering on which the transition functions are defined.  I don't think one gets any additional information from knowing that the trivial bundle $F$ in question is a subbundle of a larger (possibly nontrivial) bundle $E$.  Also, it is not true in general that a basis of sections for a subbundle can be extended globally to a basis for a larger bundle.

Comment: Yes, I intended to use that linear algebra fact locally on $0\to F_x\to E_x\to E_x/F_x\to 0$. However, what is the trivial cocycle $1$? Do you mean a coboundary?

Comment: The trivial cocycle 1 is the cocycle whose values are all equal to 1.  A cocycle it cohomologous to the trivial cocycle if and only if it is a coboundary.

Comment: Dear Andreas, thank you. I was hoping to understand in a more explicit way trivial sub-bundles of a given bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Vector bundle is trivial iff the transition functions have the form $g_{ij}=g_{i}g_{j}^{-1}$ where $g_i \in {\rm{GL}}(n,\mathcal{O}_{U_i})$.

Composite the trivilization with $g_i^{-1}$ we get another trivilization and the new transition functions are $g_{ij}\equiv{1}$.